# Javascript for loop function not working in another function

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop

The function "reversedcurrConvert", which contains a for loop and which is called in function checkCashRegister, is working only from index 1 onwards. Curiously it does not work for index 0 which is cid[0][0]. Can't wrap my head around what could've caused this behaviour.

```js
function reversedcurrConvert(cid) {
  for (let i = 0; i < cid.length; i++) {
    if (i = 0) {
      cid[i][0] = "PENNY"
    }
    if (i = 1) {
      cid[i][0] = "NICKEL"
    }
    if (i = 2) {
      cid[i][0] = "DIME"
    }
    if (i = 3) {
      cid[i][0] = "QUARTER"
    }
    if (i = 4) {
      cid[i][0] = "ONE"
    }
    if (i = 5) {
      cid[i][0] = "FIVE"
    }
    if (i = 6) {
      cid[i][0] = "TEN"
    }
    if (i = 7) {
      cid[i][0] = "TWENTY"
    }
    if (i = 8) {
      cid[i][0] = "ONE HUNDRED"
    }
  }
  return cid
}

function checkCashRegister(price, cash, cid) {
  let change = {}

  cid[0][0] = 0.01;
  cid[1][0] = 0.05;
  cid[2][0] = 0.1;
  cid[3][0] = 0.25;
  cid[4][0] = 1;
  cid[5][0] = 5;
  cid[6][0] = 10;
  cid[7][0] = 20;
  cid[8][0] = 100;

  change['status'] = "CLOSED"
  change['change'] = reversedcurrConvert(cid)
  return change

}

console.log(checkCashRegister(19.5, 20, [
  ["PENNY", 0.5],
  ["NICKEL", 0],
  ["DIME", 0],
  ["QUARTER", 0],
  ["ONE", 0],
  ["FIVE", 0],
  ["TEN", 0],
  ["TWENTY", 0],
  ["ONE HUNDRED", 0]
]));
```

Comment: `i=0` is an assignment, not a comparison.

Comment: how is i=0 different from i=1, i=2... etc., i.e. why doesn't i=0 work while the others do? Is i=1/2/3... not an assignment?

Comment: Those are all assignments too (and equally a problem). I suggest reading a(-nother?) tutorial, e.g. https://javascript.info/

Comment: *"how is i=0 different from.."* ... `if(i=0)` is saying `if(0)` since use an assignment, and thus it's saying `if(false)` so it never leads to anything and get's "skipped".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem that you must use `i == x` in your loop instead of `i = x`. The second problem you do a lot of unnecessary `if`. Here is example how you can easily set the value by using object as map

```js
function reversedcurrConvert(cid) {
  const banknoteName = {
    0: 'PENNY',
    1: 'NICKEL',
    2: 'DIME',
    3: 'QUARTER',
    4: 'ONE',
    5: 'FIVE',
    6: 'TEN',
    7: 'TWENTY',
    8: 'ONE HUNDRED',
  };
  
  for (let i = 0; i < cid.length; ++i) {
    cid[i][0] = banknoteName[i];
  }
  
  return cid;
}

function checkCashRegister(price, cash, cid) {
  let change = {}

  cid[0][0] = 0.01;
  cid[1][0] = 0.05;
  cid[2][0] = 0.1;
  cid[3][0] = 0.25;
  cid[4][0] = 1;
  cid[5][0] = 5;
  cid[6][0] = 10;
  cid[7][0] = 20;
  cid[8][0] = 100;

  change['status'] = 'CLOSED';
  change['change'] = reversedcurrConvert(cid);
  
  return change
}

console.log(checkCashRegister(19.5, 20, [
  ["PENNY", 0.5],
  ["NICKEL", 0],
  ["DIME", 0],
  ["QUARTER", 0],
  ["ONE", 0],
  ["FIVE", 0],
  ["TEN", 0],
  ["TWENTY", 0],
  ["ONE HUNDRED", 0]
]));
```

P.S. I really didn't clearly understand why you at first time set numbers into `cid[x][0]` and then set `string` with `for` loop. When you pass `cid` into `reversedcurrConvert` function you pass pointer to this array not it's copy, if you don't know. Because of it when you change value in your `reversedcurrConvert` function you also change values of `cid` in `checkCashRegister` function. So you can set this strings without looping as you do it before calling `reversedcurrConvert` function

Comment: I can't believe i missed that. Thanks so much for pointing out my blind spot.

Comment: @tommy-ling Was happy to help!